# Django forms template dropdown with unique identifier for each iteration of a forloop

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to generate a unique ID for each iteration of a for loop item.
The item generated is a drop down menu and the number of times it s generated will depend on the number of incidents that are active.
The the problem I am having is that the ID of the dropdown is the same for each dropdown menu. In this case id="id_status" when viewed via the browser page source

Is there a way to generate for example id="id_status_1" for the first dropdown, then id="id_status_2" for the second one and so on?

I tried to implement something with forloop.counter and also javascript's setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier"), but have been racking my brain for hours now without success

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
...
...

class IncidentStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status
```

**forms.py:**

```
from .models import IncidentStatus
...
...

class IncidentStatusAssigneeForm(ModelForm):
    status = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=IncidentStatus.objects.all().order_by('status'), empty_label='Select a Status', label='')

    class Meta:
        model = IncidentStatus
        fields = ('status',)
```

**views.py: (for formset attempt)**

```
from .models import IncidentStatus
from .forms import IncidentStatusAssigneeForm
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
...
...

def set_status(req):
    all_incidents = Incident.objects.all
    
    test_status_formset = modelformset_factory(IncidentStatus, form=IncidentStatusAssigneeForm)
    test_status = test_status_formset()
    ...
    ...
    
    context = {'test_status': test_status, 'all_incidents': all_incidents, ....}
    
    return render(req, 'incident_main/assignee.html', context)
```

***original views.py:***

```
from .models import IncidentStatus
from .forms import IncidentStatusAssigneeForm
...
...

def set_status(req):
    test_status = IncidentStatusAssigneeForm()
    all_incidents = Incident.objects.all
    ...
    ...
    
    context = {'test_status ': test_status, 'all_incidents': all_incidents, ....}
    
    return render(req, 'incident_main/assignee.html', context)
```

**template.html:**

```
{% for incident in all_incidents %} 
...
...
    {{ test_status  }}
...
... 
{% endfor %}
```

**view page source result**

```
<select name="status" required id="id_status">
  <option value="" selected>Select a Status</option>

  <option value="9">Acknowledged</option>

  <option value="12">General status update</option>

  <option value="2">In Progress (assessment and diagnostics)</option>

  <option value="10">In Progress (repairs/remedial action)</option>

  <option value="3">Pending (awaiting feedback from requestor)</option>

  <option value="5">Pending (awaiting parts/tools)</option>

  <option value="4">Pending (call logged with service provider)</option>

  <option value="7">Resolved</option>

</select>
```

The above result will be the same for all iterations of the for loop, as each dropdown is tied to its own task. As can be seen the ID generated is id="id_status". This is the value I am trying to make unique for each dropdown

EDIT:
Added attempt code for formset. Only change is to views.py and the html template

Comment: Please use a formset...

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Willem. I am busy watching a video on how to do this and it seems like it might work for my purpose. Will wait on other answers while I try to implement a formset solution

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. Not sure if you are still available to assist. I managed to implement the formset, but I am getting multiple dropdowns per task item. Is there a setting to get just one drop down per loop iteration. Please see image link of what I am getting. https://i.postimg.cc/PJfBNYHV/formset.png

Comment: can you share the current attempt (code), edit the question.

Comment: Hi Willem. I have edited the post. The only change is in views where I imported the modelformset_factory and created the formset in the set_status function.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. From what I can see, the number of dropdowns been generated are been based on the number of items in the model itself. There are a total of 13 items/rows for the 'Status' model some of which have been filtered out depending on permissions level. This seems to match what is shown in the image I posted.

Comment: You don't need to iterate, `{{ test_status }}` does that automatically, creating a new form in the template for each form in the form*set*.

Comment: @raphael. Thanks you. I noticed the same thing but {{ test_status }} has to be run within the for loop. There is alot going on there which is supposed to link together for each iteration (probably bad code design on my side). I'm not sure if you saw the previous code before the edit which was working as expected except for the non-unique identifiers been generated. I will reedit and add the original aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put this as an answer for now, since it's too long for a comment, and then I'll delete / adjust it.

If I understand what you're after correctly, then you don't want a formset for IncidentStatus, indeed perhaps you don't need a an IncidentStatus model *at all*.  You seem to have about 10-15 different choices for status, so you could just use [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) in your `Incident` model.  Then you can use a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/), specifically, a [modelformset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), but not for `IncidentStatus`, rather for `Incident`.  Then you will not need to iterate, the formset factory will create a new form for each object in the Incident model, with it's own form.

Comment: Thank you again. The idea behind the model was that values can be edited or added against the database from a template form POST submission without having to do it directly in the py file or Django admin. Though what you write does make sense  and maybe I have overcomplicated things. As it is getting late this side, I will give it a shot tomorrow and post back if I am successful.

Comment: Work got in the way of me attending to this sooner. I did try your method of having choices directly in the model and it worked accordingly, but the client did specify that they want to be able to ammend that one as well as other lists as the need arises so I have put that part of the spec on the todo list until I find a more appropriate solution. As your answer does acheive the unique ID generation requirements I laid out, I will mark it as the answer since no other appropriate solution has been provided. Thank you

Comment: Tuamks!l @David